# index.tsx:532 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...)' as it is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

My code has a component called `MainLayout`:

MainLayout.jsx

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import Header from "../Common/Header";
import Footer from "../Common/Footer";

export default function MainLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Header />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Header.jsx:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Header() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hrader");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="Header">
      <div>
        <h1>Train</h1>
        <h3>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </h3>

        <h3>
          <Link to={"/#contact"}>Contact</Link>
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import MainLayout from "./../Layout/MainLayout";
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { router } from "../../routes/router";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <MainLayout>
      <ToastContainer />
    </MainLayout>
  );
}
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import App from "./components/Containers/App";
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { router } from "./routes/router";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

router.js:

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./../components/Login/Login";
import Register from "../components/Register/Register";
import Home from "../components/Common/Home";

export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: "/login", element: <Login /> },
  { path: "/register", element: <Register /> },
  { path: "/", element: <Home /> },
]);
```

But when running, 21 errors occur in my program, which are mainly the following errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of
> 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...)' as it is null.
>
> react-dom.development.js:18687  The above error occurred in the
> <Link> component:

I have no idea how to fix it.

I'm in the file router.js below routes
I put `{basename:"/"}` but it kept giving me an error.

Whether I put `{basename:"/"}` or not, the above errors occur again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`App` which renders `MainLayout` which renders `Header` which renders `Link` components are all rendered ***outside*** the routing context that `RouterProvider` provides.

Convert `App` into a layout route component (*e.g. it renders an `Outlet`*) and move it into the routes.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <MainLayout>
      <Outlet />
      <ToastContainer />
    </MainLayout>
  );
}
```

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./components/Containers/App";
import Login from "./../components/Login/Login";
import Register from "../components/Register/Register";
import Home from "../components/Common/Home";

export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      { path: "/login", element: <Login /> },
      { path: "/register", element: <Register /> },
      { path: "/", element: <Home /> },
    ]
  },
]);
```

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { router } from "./routes/router";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Your answer was very good. My problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Update your main file from:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

to:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

So you need to remove the `<App/>` component, since you already have the components to render each route defined in your `router` export.